# Return all values as a varchar in select statement

Tags: sqlite

I need to build a varchar of all return values of my select statement. Is it possible to do this within the select statement ?

Let's day i have this table:

```
Name          Age               City
Daniel        30                Stockholm
Robert        30                Gothenburgh
Lisa          28                Skane
Mikael        35                Norrland
Annelie       25                Norrkoping
```

The Query i've tried so far:

```
SELECT ' N50 ' || Name || ' A51 ' || Age || ' C60 ' || City || ' END ' FROM tablename WHERE condition
```

But this return values on several rows and not in the format i want.

The result i want is following:

```
N50 Daniel A51 30 C60 Stockholm END N50 Robert A51 30 C60 Gothenburgh END N50 Lisa A51 28 C60 Skane END N50 Mikael A51 35 C60 Norrland END N50 Annelie A51 25 C60 Norrkoping END
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with group_concat(x)

Comment: To answer the question, write an answer.

Comment: Isn't it a comma, that separates columns in the select? Like `SELECT column0, column1 FROM table`

Comment: @metadings A comma makes a new column in the result and yes that is the usual case. However if you want more control about how the result looks (usually when adressing "prettiness" for a human eye), using the concatenation operator `||`is a possible tool.

Comment: Do the values of the involved coumns contain linefeeds, e.g. `\n`? 
Please make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQLIte, an MCVE includes a `.dump` of your SQLITE database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(group_concat(one),',','') from (SELECT ' N50 ' || Name || ' A51 ' || Age || ' C60 ' || City || ' END ' as one FROM toy where 1=1);
```

- use OPs query to make a table on the fly with concatenated one row, as column `one`
- pickup comments proposal to use `group_concat()`, apply it to on-the-fly table
- add a `replace` to get rid of the obviously unwanted `,`
- tablename is "toy"
- your `condition` is represented as `1=1`